# SQL Server CE 3.0 - Deleting Rows in Windows 10

Tags: windows, sql-server-ce

We have databases that are using SQL Server CE 3.0 and are having an issue when it comes to running the DELETE command on a Windows 10 PC.

For whatever reason, the `DELETE` command doesn't like the greater than (>) symbol and throws an error

> An internal error occurred. [ID = 3640]

every time we try to run the command.

You can run the same command as a `SELECT` statement and it will work but the `DELETE` refuses to work. I also tried using `BETWEEN` and it didn't like that either.

ex.

```
DELETE FROM [TableName] 
WHERE [Time] > '8/22/2016 4:00:00 PM'
```

The less than (`<`) symbol works fine as well, it's just the greater than one that seems to be the problem.

Has anyone else experienced this or know how to resolve/work-around?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Okay, so apparently it just doesn't like DateTime fields as I can do a delete with on our identity seed column...strange...

Comment: How are you running those commands? That does not look like the [default date format](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12031551/) for SQL CE. Try using [Cast or Convert](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174450(v=sql.110).aspx) to specify a date in quotes.

Comment: I did try using Cast and Convert as well but still received the error message. The calls are made from our VB.Net application using the SqlCeCommand.